# Splitting polygon by sections obtained from IDW interpolation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, polygon, splitting, inverse-distance-weighted

I used IDW to show the rainfall pattern over a region ... the attached picture show the result ... my area split into three ranges that show 3 different colors...

How can I split one original polygon to three based on the boundary of colors or can the boundary be shown by lines?

My goal is to apply the new boundary one different heatmap.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. You can separate the vector based on the features, but we will need some more information. Can you right click the layer in the table of contents, then click view attribute table and screenshot the results?

Comment: Reclassify you raster, convert to polygons.